# Set focus on ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview

I've just starting using ListView control in VS2019.

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I can't figure out how to set the focus on the control like I can with most other controls.

I want the ListView to be focused when the form loads, and then I want to programmatically focus an item in the ListView.

I know how to focus a particular item using `ListView1.FocusedItem.Index`, but I can't focus the actual control.

I have tried both `ListView1.Select()` and `ListView1.Focus()` but these seem to do nothing.

What am I missing!?

Thanks

**EDIT**
As pointed out below, the control is actually focused using ListView1.Select() it's just not focused in the same way I'd expect, for example, a ListBox to be focused - ie, with a particular item in the list highlighted.

How would you best focus the ListView and highlight a particular item?
I have tried this in a command button on the form, but it doesn't do anything. Though it works correctly AFTER I click an Item in the ListView.

```
ListView1.Select()
If (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
    ListView1.Items(4).Selected = True
End If
```

Comment: My guess would be that you're trying to focus the control in the `Load` event handler, which is useless.  Either set the `TabIndex` properties of your controls so that the control you want initially focused is first in line or else call `Select` on the control you want focused in the `Shown` event handler, which is executed AFTER the form is displayed for the first time rather than BEFORE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't seem to locate the shown event handler for this particular control though?

Comment: I think the Shown event jmcilhinney is meaning is on the form, not controls

Comment: Yes you are correct, the Shown event relates to the form. This works, though doesn't quite solve my issue which I have added to the original post above,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listview1.focus()

For I as Integer = 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListView1.Items(i).Text = "youritemtexthere" then
         ListView1.Items(i).Selected = true
    End If
End For
```

or if you have the index but not a known text just do:

```
listview1.focus()
ListView1.Items(index).Selected = true
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView1.Select` works, you probably just don't see that the ListView has focus. You can verify this by checking the GotFocus and LostFocus events on the ListView:

```
Private Sub ListView1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.GotFocus
    Me.Text = "Got Focus"
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.LostFocus
    Me.Text = "Lost Focus"
End Sub
```

This simply updates your Form's title to "Got Focus" or "Lost Focus". You can force the focus in your Form Load event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ListView1.Items.Add("a")
    ListView1.Items.Add("b")
    ListView1.Items.Add("c")

    ListView1.Select()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Etienne, you are correct, the control is focused just not in the way I expected. I have updated the original post with a bit more info on my particular issue